# How to order ASC on scolling cursor backward pagination in SQLLite?

Tags: sqlite, pagination

I've implemented the scrolling cursor example below from http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ScrollingCursor

To scroll forward:

```
SELECT title FROM tracks
WHERE singer='Madonna'
AND title>:lasttitle
ORDER BY title
LIMIT 5;
```

To scroll backward:

```
SELECT title FROM tracks
WHERE singer='Madonna'
AND title<:firsttitle
ORDER BY title DESC
LIMIT 5;
```

It works, but I was wondering if there is a way to do backwards pagination like in the second query, only have the results displayed ASC, as currently the order is displayed reversed. Or is it a matter of using that query to get your result, and then your app code to order the results array however you want?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are paging backwards, you get the records beginning from the end of the page.

If you really want to get the records ordered in the order way, you can sort them again with another query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT title
      FROM tracks
      WHERE singer = 'Madonna'
        AND title < :firsttitle
      ORDER BY title DESC
      LIMIT 5)
ORDER BY title
```